# In the Stanford NLP POS tagger, setting normalizeParenthese=True changes the POS results

Tags: stanford-nlp

I may have found a bug in the POS tagger. The tagging results change whether I use the "-tokenizerOptions" flag with "normalizeParentheses=True" or False. I'm accessing the tagger from python using a server set up via:

```
pos_args=['java', '-mx400m', '-cp', homedir+'/models/stanfordpostagger.jar','edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTaggerServer','-model','english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger','-port','2021','-loadClassifier',english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','-tokenizerOptions','normalizeParentheses=true']
POS=Popen(pos_args)
```

and I use the [SNER](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sner/0.2) package to actually do the tagging.

If I tag the sentence "(Bob is nice)" with normalizeParentheses=true, I get:

```
[(u'-LRB-', u'-LRB-'),
 (u'Bob', u'NNP'),
 (u'is', u'VBZ'),
 (u'nice', u'JJ'),
 (u'-RRB-', u'-RRB-')]
```

But if I use normalizeParentheses=false, I get:

```
[(u'(', u'NNP'),
 (u'Bob', u'NNP'),
 (u'is', u'VBZ'),
 (u'nice', u'JJ'),
 (u')', u'NN')]
```

and this version of the tagger also marks many words as foreign ('FW') when they aren't.

I've tried experimenting with many other options, and only this one and the normalizeOtherBrackets=False seem to cause this behavior. It is as if these two options cause a totally different tagger method to be used. I'm curious if this is indeed a bug or if there is a clever workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize the parentheses when using the POS tagger.  It was trained on data that has normalized parentheses.